# Merging two lists that inserts all parameters from list2 to list1

Tags: python-2.7

Suppose I have two lists of objects

```
List1 = [{"name" : "Mac", "age":24, "id" : 1},
         {"name" : "Mona","age":22, "id" : 2}]
```

and

```
List2 = [{"type" : "human","country":"AUS"}]
```

How do I append all elements from List 2 to all the elements of list 1
so that the final list1 would look like

```
[{"name" : "Mac", "age":24, "id" : 1, "type" : "human","country":"AUS"},{"name" : "Mona", "age":22, "id" : 2, "type" : "human","country":"AUS"}]
```

Currently am looping through and doing an update on list which is working but I want to know if there's an easier and better way to do this

```
for person in List1:    
  person.update(List2) 
print List1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List1 = [{"name" : "Mac", "age":24, "id" : 1},
     {"name" : "Mona","age":22, "id" : 2}]

List2 = [{"type" : "human","country":"AUS"}]

List1 = List1 + List2
```

This will work, I've checked in Python 2.7. Hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below code-

```
List1 = [{"name" : "Mac", "age":24, "id" : 1},
     {"name" : "Mona","age":22, "id" : 2}]

List2 = [{"type" : "human","country":"AUS"}]

finalList = [dict(l.items() + List2[0].items()) for l in List1]

print finalList
```